# Which process was responsible for an event signalled by inotify?

Tags: python, inotify, pyinotify

I am using `pyinotify` to detect access, changes, etc. on files in a given directory. Is there an easier way to find out which process was responsible for that - without having to [patch `inotify`](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0603.1/0166.html)?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/320716/find-out-which-process-is-changing-a-file

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, that information isn't in the `struct inotify_event` sent by the kernel.

Actually there isn't any guarantee that the process responsible is still running when you get the event.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on Linux (pyinotify would tend to indicate this) you could use SELinux (running in permissive mode of course) to wrap a process(es) and log all their file access/creation/deletion/etc.